# Getting values of selected item in ListView with multiple fields in c#, windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list view with multiple fields, and the problem is that I can't get the value from columns other then the first one.

When I call `lv.SelectedItems[0]` I get the first column, but everything other then 0 for index gives me this error: `Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of`1`is not valid for`index`.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`SubItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
var item = lv.SelectedItems[0];

var firstColumn = item.SubItems[0].Text;
var secondColumn = item.SubItems[1].Text;
...
```